# Add arg to launch file

Tags: parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, launch, ros, depth

Instead of running a package using command line, I made a launch file

Commande line:

```
rosrun image_view image_saver image:=/the-rgb-image-topic
```

Launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/rgb/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Now I want to do the same for this:

```
rosrun image_view image_saver image:=/camera/depth/image _encoding:=16UC1
```

How can I add the argument to the launch file..

I think I should start it like that

```
<launch>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/rgb/image_raw"/>

  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/depth/image"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Comment: have a look to the [roslaunch XML documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) and in particular to the [`<arg>` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg).

Comment: @alextoind: If I understand it correctly, the OP wants to set the argument within the launch-file. The `arg` tag would be used to pass arguments to the launch-file when launching it.

Comment: @luator, yes probably you are right, but you can also use the `default` attribute of the `<arg>` tag to provide the default behaviour as in your answer plus an external access to that parameter, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

To pass arbitrary arguments to nodes in launch-files, you can use the `args` attribute of the [`node` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes):

```
<node name="image_saver" pkg="image_view" type="image_saver" args="_encoding:=16UC1" ...>
```

However, in this specific case there is a better way: `_encoding` is not just some arbitrary argument but it is a *parameter* that is handled by the [ROS Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server). While it will probably work, using the `args` attribute, the nicer way is to use the [`param` tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param):

```
<node name="image_saver" pkg="image_view" type="image_saver">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/depth/image" />
    <param name="encoding" value="16UC1" type="string" />
</node>
```